# CKEditor how to allow all styles for all tags while still restricting the tags themselves

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I use CKEditor's allowedContent option to restrict specific HTML tags while still allowing those tags to have any styles.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to add this:

```
'*': {
    styles: '*'
}
```

in my allowedContent object. In plain English: For all tags, allow all styles.

Comment: Or more precisely - allow all styles for tags allowed by other rules.